# ruby on rails associations - removing something which doesn't exist in the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations, counter

So I have a model foo which has_and_belongs_to_many bar.

foo.bar gives me all the bars associated with foo. Every time I delete a bar, I call Foo.decrement_counter(:bar_count, self[:id]) via the :after_remove callback.

I am testing the removal of a bar which is not associated with foo. This too decrements the counter... which I don't want. How do I ensure that the counter is decremented only when a bar is actually deleted from the association?

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :bar, :after_remove => :dec_bar_count, :after_add => :inc_bar_count, :uniq => true

def dec_bar_count(record)
  Foo.decrement_counter(:bar_count, self[:id])
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the full code you're using for your `after_remove` callback?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why no just use `Foo.bar.count`

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what it is you're counting, but it seems like you're trying to duplicate the counting functionality already in ActiveRecord.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344744/rails-caching-db-queries-and-best-practices) may also be related, regarding DB caching in Rails.

Comment: I want to store the count in the db so that I don't have to compute Foo.bar.count every time I want to retrieve a count, since I expect the size of the association to get very large. Moreover, using Foo.bar.count is not concurrent friendly because it first SELECT COUNT(*) and then UPDATES the counter column.

Comment: Rails will cache DB work for you, so it won't recalculate it every time. It caches the answer to the count, and if a record is added/removed (in any thread) it will be marked as "dirty", be recalculated only once, and then cached again until it changes.  In other words, the Rails designers thought of this, and ActiveRecord automatically does this exact thing.